# view terminates when scrolling

Tags: iphone

my problem is, that if i scroll my table view very fast, the screen freazes. i get the following:
*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewControllerWrapperView isEqualToString:]: unrecognized*
perhaps someone can help me!
Thx

Answer (score 0):

You're over-releasing (or under-retaining) an object.